# Does a virtual function override a non-virtual function of the same name in a base class?

Tags: c++

Is the following standard conforming? Can you cite the section?

```
struct A
{
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

struct B
{
    void func(){}
};

struct C : public A, public B
{
    virtual void func(){ B::func(); }
};
```

I'm getting a strange compiler warning in VS2010 in equivalent but more complicated code pointing to `func`'s declaration in the derived-most class: `warning C4505: unreferenced local function has been removed`. I have no idea why the compiler thinks a virtual function declared in a class is a local; however I can't repro that warning in a simpler example.

## Edit:

I figured out a small repro case for the warning. I think I was going down the wrong path assuming it was related to function hiding. Here's the repro case:

```
template<typename T>
struct C
{
    int GetType() const;
    virtual int func() const;   // {return 4;}  //  Doing this inline removes the warning <--------------
};

template<typename T>
int C<T>::GetType() const
{
    return 0;
}

template<>
int C<int>::GetType() const
{
    return 12;
}

template<typename T> 
int C<T>::func() const
{
    return 3; 
}

//  Adding the following removes the warning <--------------------
//  template<>
//  int C<int>::func() const
//  {
//      return 4;
//  }
```

I'm fairly sure this is just a VS2010 bug.

Comment: "in equivalent but more complicated code ... can't repro that warning in a simpler example". Then they probably aren't equivalent.

Comment: The above code doesn't produce the warning you speak of in VS2010. There is nothing semantically wrong with it but the choice of design is odd to me.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how to repro that warning - I'll edit when/if I do.

Comment: I am inclined to mark the question for closing. You are hiding the important information. If the compiler is considering the function as local, and that points at either a `static` non-member function or an unnamed namespace, none of which show in your code. You might want to add that information here, and once you add it, note that because the function is *local* it is not accessible **outside** the current translation unit, so if it is not used **inside** the TU, then noone can really use it and the compiler can very well remove it.

Comment: Also note that the question's title and the question contents are unrelated. The answer to the title is **no**, it *hides* it. Also note that `struct C { virtual void f(); };` contains a *declaration*, but `struct C { virtual void f() { B::func(); } };` is both a declaration and a *definition*, what is the exact line where the error is detected, the declaration (signature) or the call inside it?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas the declaration signature - I'm still working on repro

Comment: @dribeas: Because the function is `inline`, the compiler doesn't need to generate it unless it's used locally.  See my answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: a function is not *local* just because it is `inline` (I am assuming a sensible definition of *local*), but because it has internal linkage. If an inline function is not used in a translation unit, the code is not generated, but that should trigger no warning

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is well-formed.  `C::func` overrides `A::func`.  `B::func` is an unrelated function.  The spec reads (10.3/2):

> If a virtual member function `vf` is declared in a class `Base` and in a class `Derived`, derived directly or indirectly from `Base`, a member function `vf` with the same name, parameter-type-list, cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as `Base::vf` is declared, then `Derived::vf` is also virtual (whether or not it is so declared) and it overrides111 `Base::vf`.

`C::func` has the same name as `A::func` and `A::func` is virtual, therefore `C::func` overrides `A::func`.  `B::func` has no relation to `A::func`; I don't know that there is any language in the spec that expressly addresses that scenario.

The Visual C++ 11 Beta compiler does not emit any warnings or errors for this code.

Answer (score 1):

Normally virtual functions can't be eliminated by the linker as dead-code, because their addresses have to appear in the vtable.  However, if the vtable for `struct C` was determined to be dead code (which could happen if all constructors are also dead code), then that last remaining reference can be eliminated too.

Because the function is declared `inline`, this dead code removal optimization doesn't have to wait until link time; it can be done by the compiler.  The Standard says (see section 7.1.2):

> **An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used** and shall have exactly the same definition in every case (3.2).  [ Note:  A call to the inline function may be encountered before its definition appears in the translation unit.  — end note ] If the definition of a function appears in a translation unit before its first declaration as inline, the program is ill-formed.  If a function with external linkage is
>   declared inline in one translation unit, it shall be declared inline in all translation units in which it appears; no diagnostic is required.   An `inline` function with external linkage shall have the same address in all translation units.  A `static` local variable in an `extern inline` function always refers to the same object. A string literal in the body of an `extern inline` function is the same object in different translation units. [ Note:  A string literal appearing in a default argument is not in the body of an inline function merely because the expression is used in a function call from that inline function.   — end note ] A type defined within the body of an `extern inline` function is the same type in every translation unit.

If the compiler can determine the function is never used in *this* translation unit, it knows that any translation unit that does use the function must contain its own identical definition, and will generate the code.  So it can skip code generation just as if it didn't have external linkage at all.

Generating a warning is completely pointless, however, since there will be a high number of false positives (when the `inline` function IS odr-used and code generated in some other compilation unit).

Answer (score 0):

[Let me google it for you.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z85eyax0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> **`function` : unreferenced local function has been removed**
>
> The given function is local and not referenced in the body of the module; therefore, the function is dead code.
>
> The compiler did not generate code for this dead function.

The compiler statically determined that the function was unused, so it did not generate code for that function and warns you that you have useless code. A bit more involved than the usual *unused variable* warning, but about the same effect: dead code smells.

Comment: I did google it, thanks. This makes sense for `LOCAL` function only. I can't even see how the compiler would know if a function is unused, it would have to be the linker, in which case it would be a linker warning. Have you ever seen a warning about an unused virtual function in a class before? EVER?

Comment: @Dave: The function is (implicitly) declared `inline`, which means that if any other compilation unit used it, it would have to appear in that other compilation unit.  So the compiler doesn't have to worry about external references to the function, it can treat it as local.

Comment: Ahhh. Interesting. But, but, it's virtual - can it really resolve if it's called or not on that level? And actually, I'm falling back on my previous stance: Have you seen this warning in your own code for, say, a templated class with an accessor or mutator which isn't called and is inline since it's in a templated class? That's the same case right?

Comment: @Dave: There are different rules for templates, but they boil down to pretty much the same behavior, as long as you don't have explicit instantiation.